# what data type is produced by mapply()?

Tags: r

This is what my code looks like.  a, b, c, and d are scalers, e is a list of vectors.  A, B, C and D are vectors.

```
GetOutput=function(a,b,c,d){
  e=FunOther(a,b,c,d)
  i=mean(e$f)
  j=mean(e$g)
  k=abs(mean(e$h))
  return(list(b=b,i=i,j=j,k=k))
}
Output=mapply(GetOutput,A,B,C,D)
```

GetOutput will return a list of 4 scalers.  I want to factor this up to a matrix of inputs and a matrix of outputs.  I had been using a for loop but I thought I would try mapply instead.

Suppose A, B, C and D have a length 100.  I just want to get a vector with length 100 which give me all of the i's so that I can calculate their minima.  Then the same for the j's and k's.  This is part of a Monte Carlo study.   But I am having trouble understanding the Output object.  It appears to be a list of lists.  What I thought would be a one liner turns into several operations.  The best I can come up with is:

```
Output2=as.data.frame(t(Output))
OutputMeans=c(mean(as.numeric(Output2$i)),
              mean(as.numeric(Output2$j)),
              mean(as.numeric(Output2$k)))
```

This seems just bananas to me.  I though I could operate on Output directly with the mean function without having to bother with all of these transformations.

Comment: In regard to your title, "A list, or for SIMPLIFY = TRUE, a vector, array or list."

Comment: `mapply` is versatile. It allows you to handle the output format based on the `simplify` argument. However, if your data can not be simplified, it will ignore that argument. I suggest you read the documentation for `mapply` and `sapply` to understand this.

Comment: @RichardScriven Any idea what conditions determine whether it produces a vector, an array, or a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had instead written: `return( c(b=b,i=i,j=j,k=k) )` , then each element in the list from `mapply` would have been a named vector, rather than what you did get  .... a list of lists. And since the 'simplify' argument would have let you return a matrix, you could have returned a non-recursive result as well.  Because `mapply` is so versatile, it gives you multiple levels of control of the returned structure.

Another R programming tip: Don't use '$' as an extraction function inside functions. If you are sure of your column name you can use `[['colname']] but then by using '[[' you can later generalize your function to accept column names as arguments, a feature which '$' will not support.